# Which polynomial equations of higher degree will have a solution formula?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, problem-solving

A polynomial equation of degree greater than four will in general have no solution formula. But what are some typical cases one should be aware of as a practical person in which there are solutions?

Comment: By "solution formula" do you mean "solution in terms of radicals"?  "Galois Theory" is the branch of algebra that answers your question.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "formula." I want to caution you that the answers below which use the word "solvable" are doing so in a rather precise technical sense of the word (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory#Solvable_groups_and_solution_by_radicals) and it's not clear to me whether you actually care about this notion of solvability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another example that come up fairly often is $a x^{2n} + b x^n + c = 0$

Comment: Ah, that actually makes me think that maybe every polynomial equation, which can be written down as $a·X^4+...+d·X+e=0$, where $X$ made up from something solvable like $X=x^n$ might lead to a solution. (?)

Comment: Yes, of course.  If $f$ is solvable and $g - c$ is solvable for every constant $c$, then $f \circ g$ is solvable.

Answer (score 10):

The example of greatest practical importance is $x^n=1$.  The solutions are the $n$-th roots of unity. They come up moderately often in applied work, and are omnipresent in pure mathematics.

Comment: More generally, every abelian extension is solvable ;).